# preventing a function to run if form field is left empty with HTML required attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML "required" field attribute on the input field. At the same time I have a function which shows the next form field on clicking the "NEXT" button. Form validation works but the following form field still shows when clicking the "Next" button, which obviously I do not want to show.

I want to use simple and minimum amount of code.

```
<head>
<style> 
#tab2{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
function show(){
document.getElementById("tab2").style.display="block";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id="tab1">
<input type="text" id="urname" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
<button onclick="show()">Next</button>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
<input type="text" id="urname" placeholder="Your School Name" required><br>
<button>Next</button>
</div>
</form> 
</body>
```

I want to create a multi-step form with simplest and minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're making the second input display block irrespective of value of first input, instead add an if statement to check value of first input and then accordingly change the display property of second input

```js
function show() {
  let urName = document.getElementById('urname').value
  if (urName) {
    document.getElementById("tab2").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#tab2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="tab1">
      <input type="text" id="urname" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
      <button onclick="show()">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
      <input type="text" id="urname" placeholder="Your School Name" required><br>
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```